# textbox and button html/php

Tags: php, mysql

i'm new here, i'm italian and i'm 17yo , i don't speak english very well, so, sorry for my english :)

i've two problems 
the first is that i have a code like this

```
  while ($i < $number) {
      $festa[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"festa");
      $data[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"data");
      $luogo[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"luogo");
      $prezzo[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"prezzo");
      $dettagli[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"dettagli");
      $bus[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"bus");
      $organizzatore[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"organizzatore");
      $idfesta[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"ID");
      echo " <div id='latestadded'>
             <form method='post' action='paginaevento.php'>
          <input type='submit' 
          style='background-image:url(../fotoorganizzatori/$organizzatore[$i].png;' 
          class='immaginefesta' 
          name='idfesta' 
          value='$idfesta[$i]'/> <br>
           </form>

             <div class='titlebar'>
              $festa[$i] <br>
             </div>
             <div class='testievento'>
             ORGANIZZATORE : $organizzatore[$i] <br>
             DATA EVENTO : $data[$i] <br>
             PRESSO : $luogo[$i] <br>
             COSTO FESTA : $prezzo[$i] <br>
             DETTAGLI PULLMAN : $bus[$i] <br>
             FESTA Nr. : $idfesta[$i] <br>
             </div>

             </div>
             <br> ";
      $i++;
}   
}
```

it's my DIV_CREATION code, in fact it works but there's a problem with the image, because the browser doesn't load the image well, it load the only an image and i don't know why, i put here the link so you could see : http://www.melaprogramming.altervista.org/SITO/sito3/home.php

and the second question is that, i've a 'abc.html' page where i can add a new table_row in my mysql table but i want to have a textfield that save the text as i write 
ex. if i write in the textbox : 
my name
is 
andrea
the table should contains :
my name
is
andrea
with colour and other things too.
i'm very sorry for my bad english, and i hope you can help me , thank you :)

Comment: change `style='background-image:url(../fotoorganizzatori/$organizzatore[$i].png;'` to `style='background-image:url(../fotoorganizzatori/$organizzatore[$i].png)' ` you have a lingering `;` and missing a `)` that's messing it up

Comment: If you have two questions you should split them up and ask the second one separately as they don't appear to be related. Additionally you should avoid using mysql_* functions, instead make use of either the newer more secure mysqli_ or PDO for your database functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close the "url()" in your background-image.

Change it with :

```
style='background-image:url(../fotoorganizzatori/$organizzatore[$i].png);'
```

Comment: thank you, the first problem is solved, but fort the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

for the text box query is like.

$qu="CREATE TABLE $_POST['your_text_box_name'](colors varchar(10).......

then write another query to insert color and other things. Take html data with, like $_POST['color']